# At a certain point, does adding a large integer to a long integer well below its limit in Java cause problems?

Tags: java, long-integer

For example, adding *4.0E16* or *4*Math.pow(10, 16)* to:

> 5,390,195,186,705,543

The result should be:

> 45,390,195,186,705,543

but the following code returns

> 45,390,195,186,705,544

adding 1 to the least significant digit (which shouldn't be happening).

From what I've researched online the upper limit of long is:

> 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

but the example I've given has not exceeded that limit yet.

Relevant code:

```
int [] digits = new digits[] {6,1,4,5,3,9,0,1,9,5,1,8,6,7,0,5,5,4,3};
long sum = new Long(0);
int k = digits.length-1;

for(int j = digits.length-1; j>=0; j--)
{

    sum = (long) (sum +  (long)digits[j]*Math.pow(10, k-j));
}
```

Comment: Why not check against `Long.MAX_VALUE`? What kinds of problems are you expecting? The sum of would just overflow, not error out

Comment: By the way ```long sum = new Long(0)``` creates a Long object with initial value 0, then converts it to a simply type long, then the Object gets discarded. better write ```long sum = 0l```.

Comment: Math.pow works on `double`. So you will get rounding errors for large numbers. The addition itself (using long) is fine.

Comment: @Stefan Recommended way is `0L` (uppercase L).

Answer (score 2):

The `Math.pow` function operates only on `double` values. You're using ints here, but they are silently transformed into doubles because that's the only available method, and the java language spec allows for silent widening conversions.

The problem is, 'widening' a long into a double isn't actually entirely lossless. 52 of the 64 bits available to a double are for the number itself, the rest is for the 'magnitude' (and I'm oversimplifying here, by quite a bit), whereas for a long, the entire 63 bits available are for the number itself, with no bits for magnitude. Which means doubles can represent larger (and smaller (fracitional)) numbers, but can't represent every number within the range it can represent.

That's why you are observing these 'errors'. It's just how doubles work. For more on the way doubles work, see [0.30000000000000004.com](https://0.30000000000000004.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The following few lines demonstrate what went wrong:

```
double a=  Math.pow(10, 16)*  4.0;
long   b = (long) a;
long   c = 5390195186705543L + b;

long   d = (long) (5390195186705543L + 4L * Math.pow(10, 16));
long   e = 5390195186705543L + 4L * (long) Math.pow(10, 16);

System.out.println("a="+a+" b="+b+" c="+c+" d = "+d+" e="+e);
```

Outputs:

```
a=4.0E16 b=40000000000000000 c=45390195186705543 
d = 45390195186705544 e=45390195186705543
```

**a**, **b** and **c** have all the expected value, so you see that the addition of long integers works as expected.

In case of **d** we have the wrong result because `Math.pow(10, 16)` returns a double, so the whole expression is evaluated as double and then finally converted to long integer. So we do add double values here, not integers. Double has a limited precision, which leads to a slightly wrong result.

The example **e** produces the correct result because we first convert the double to long before adding it to the other long integer values. In this case we do not loose precision because `40000000000000000` can happily be stored into a double exactly. But be careful, that does not work so good with all possible numbers.

Always keep in mind that floating point data types are not 100% precise. Therefore a good rule is that man should never compare two float or double values for equality. For example slighty more complex expressions than `1.0/3.0 + 1.0/3.0 + 1.0/3.0 == 1.0` could fail.

If you need predictable results with a certain number of digits, better use `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

Math.pow() produces a value of type *double*. The format of *double* is defined by  standard IEEE 754, see [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/jls13.pdf).

According to this standard, to 52 bits are used to store significant bits. This means it is possible to represent numbers with not more than 15 decimal digits without loss. Also *some* numbers up to 17 decimal digits can be represented, but there are "breaks" between them where the numbers are represented incorrectly.

In your case precise are only the first 15 decimal digits. The further digits *may or may not be correct*.

Here is an example that shows that:

```
public class DoublePrecisionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("45390195186705540   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705540d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705541   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705541d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705542   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705542d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705543   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705543d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705544   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705544d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705545   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705545d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705546   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705546d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705547   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705547d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705548   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705548d);
        System.out.printf("45390195186705549   --> %20.0f\n", 45390195186705549d);
    }

}
```

This will produce following result:

```
45390195186705540   -->    45390195186705536
45390195186705541   -->    45390195186705544
45390195186705542   -->    45390195186705544
45390195186705543   -->    45390195186705544
45390195186705544   -->    45390195186705544
45390195186705545   -->    45390195186705544
45390195186705546   -->    45390195186705544
45390195186705547   -->    45390195186705544
45390195186705548   -->    45390195186705552
45390195186705549   -->    45390195186705552
```

This shows that for the first number only the first 15 decimal digits are correct. For many numbers also the the 16th digit is correct. And in once case, 45390195186705544, even 17 digits are correct.

If you need a higher precision, consider using *BigDecimal* instead of *double*.